# Ubuntu 16.04 install stuck at splash screen

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, uefi, intel

I currently have a dual boot consisting of Windows 10 on /sda1-2, and OpenSuse 42.1 Tumbleweed on /sda3-7. What I'm trying to do is install Ubuntu x86_64 in place of OpenSUSE. I'm able to boot the image from USB, however, when I get to the Ubuntu screen (with the dots), the installation stops. Dots continue to move, and no HD or USB activity. I've tried waiting for over 15 minutes, and still no response. All solutions I've come across have to do with an nvidia issue, however, I'm using a System76 Notebook, which is using an Intel i915 chipset.

I've even tried installing from other flash drives, DVD, and even other flavors of Ubuntu, with no luck. I checked to see if I'm using UEFI or BIOS mode, and I am in fact using Legacy boot, and both Windows 10 and openSUSE are in legacy boot.

If it helps, I dont get the GRUB install menu, goes right to the initial purple screen. I flashed the iso via dd, with block size of 1M and sync'd the image afterward.

Comment: Have you tried `nomodeset`?

Comment: try hitting `ESC` after choosing to boot from the install media.

Comment: ESC did the trick. That's so odd, I've installed Ubuntu on this notebook dozens of times (distro-hopping), and I've never had to do that before! Side note, if I wait to hit ESC at the Ubuntu screen, I get a message saying something to the effect that the keyboard has no output(sic).